# Is a topological space with a minimal dense subset, finite?

Tags: general-topology

$(X,\mathcal T)$ is a topological space and $A$ is dense in it and for each dense $B$, we have:
$$B\subseteq A\to B=A$$
Is $X$ finite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if $\tau$ is the indiscrete topology, that is, $\tau=\{\varnothing,X\}$? Now every singleton is dense in $X$. Thus, if $A=\{x_0\}$ and $B$ is dense in $X$ with $B\subseteq A$, we have $B=A$.

Comment: I like your's as well!  and was quite surprised to see it (temporarily) disappear.

Answer (score 6):

Not necessarily.  If $( X , \mathcal{T} )$ is a discrete space, then $X$ is the *only* dense subset.  So any infinite discrete space will be a counterexample.

Comment: +$1$ I like your counterexample!

Answer (score 3):

Any infinite topological space of [Cantor-Bendixson rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_set_%28mathematics%29#Cantor.E2.80.93Bendixson_rank) one without condensation points is an example: the set of isolated points is a minimal dense subset.

For instance, take a sequence $(x_n)$ in a metric space with finitely many limit points $y_1,...,y_m$. Then $X= \{x_n \mid n \geq 0 \} \cup \{y_1,...,y_m\}$ and $A= \{x_n \mid n \geq 0\}$ is an example.

Other examples are ordinals less than $\omega_1$.